# JavaScript how to draw after image onload

Tags: javascript

I am trying to put images as objects in an imageCollection array and draw them based on the layerId property. 
I try some demo but it failed because the draw function does not occur after all images load. 
The JS fiddle : 
https://jsfiddle.net/gajw6st3/2/#&togetherjs=hLH83bLrad

```
img.onload = function() { 

var imageData = {
  image: img,
  layerId: 1  
};
imageCollection.push(imageData);
alert("size after sofa is added : "+imageCollection.length);

}
```

I expect for alerts to show like :
size after sofa is added : 1
size after bed is added : 2
size in draw function : 2
but sometimes it shows as size in draw function before both/either size after sofa/bed is added. 
How do I make sure all the images are loaded and pushed into imageCollection so that I can draw them later?
Thanks

Comment: For one, I strongly suggest you define onload BEFORE changing the src.

Comment: Secondly you need to call draw from inside the last onload

Answer (score 0):

For one, I strongly suggest you define onload BEFORE changing the src. – mplungjan 6 mins ago

Secondly you need to call draw from inside the last onload

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ez93sxpt/

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  var imageData = {
    image: img,
    layerId: 1
  };
  imageCollection.push(imageData);
  console.log("size after sofa is added : " + imageCollection.length);
}
img.src = "https://...";
```